# Split large file into smaller files

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, file, unix

I recently suggested [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751000/split-large-text-filearound-50gb-into-multiple-files-using-python) for emulating the Unix utility split in Python.

Is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Assume that the file chunks are too large to be held in memory. Assume that only one line can be held in memory.

```
import contextlib

def modulo(i,l):
    return i%l

def writeline(fd_out, line):
    fd_out.write('{}\n'.format(line))

file_large = 'large_file.txt'
l = 30*10**6  # lines per split file
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    fd_in = stack.enter_context(open(file_large))
    for i, line in enumerate(fd_in):
        if not modulo(i,l):
           file_split = '{}.{}'.format(file_large, i//l)
           fd_out = stack.enter_context(open(file_split, 'w'))
        fd_out.write('{}\n'.format(line))
```

---

I ran the Unix utility `time` and the Python module `cProfile`. Here is what I found (methods not comparable, as I was running other processes, but gives a good indication of slow parts of code):

Ugo's method:

```
tottime filename:lineno(function)
473.088 {method 'writelines' of '_io._IOBase' objects}

485.36 real       362.04 user        58.91 sys
```

My code:

```
tottime function
243.532 modulo
543.031 writeline
419.366 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
1169.735 {method 'write' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}

3207.60 real      2291.42 user        44.64 sys
```

The Unix utility split:

```
1676.82 real       268.92 user      1399.16 sys
```

Comment: the use of contextlib makes things a bit complexe to me. You could keep the same code and simply close fd_out before opening a new file. This would make the code a lot clearer.

Comment: But how can I open a file using the with statement without using contextlib? Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. Can you post your solution?

Comment: yes I was speaking about getting rid of the with statement for `fd_out`s. It is a bit ugly, you open many files and close them all at the end while you could just open and close on the fly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no chunks methods in the standard library.
But this makes things rather neat.

```
from itertools import chain, islice

def chunks(iterable, n):
   "chunks(ABCDE,2) => AB CD E"
   iterable = iter(iterable)
   while True:
       yield chain([next(iterable)], islice(iterable, n-1))

l = ...
file_large = 'large_file.txt'
with open(file_large) as bigfile:
    for i, lines in enumerate(chunks(bigfile, l)):
        file_split = '{}.{}'.format(file_large, i)
        with open(file_split, 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the file chunks are too large to be held in memory.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen ok that should be fine then lines is a generator only holding one line plus an iterator on the rest of the chunk `print type(lines)` `<type 'itertools.chain'>`.

Comment: I finally had time to have a proper look at your answer. I really appreciate the beauty of your solution! As you mention yourself it is memory efficient, because lines is an iterator yielded by the generator chunks. Your solution is also fast. I will edit my answer and show a comparison between the unix utility split, your solution and my solution. Your answer made me further aware of the power of iterators! Thanks!

Comment: I think you should leave this as an answer to the original question on SO.

Comment: Note that I quickly tried to benchmark my code too and for a 1gb file cut in 3, I have something like: Unix Split: ~3s, python2.7: ~6s, python3.3: ~15s (same with encoding='latin-1')

Comment: Should this code work in Python 3? I want to run it on a video or binary file in order to do multi-part uploads, but I'm receiving `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 51: invalid continuation byte` on `next(iterable)`. It worked with Python 2.

Comment: Answering my own question. The trick on Python 3 is to open in the files in binary mode with `'rb'` and `'wb'`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Now, there is a pypi module available that you can use to split files of any size into chunks with optimum use of memory. Check out [filesplit](https://pypi.org/project/filesplit/).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you provide sample usage of that module? I also suggest you read [Simon's answer to this meta post: _Short answers and code-only answers_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1466/120114)